# SSIS Script Component as Source throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, ssis, nullreferenceexception

I have a DataFlow where there is a Script Component as a Source.

I have defined the Output (OutputRows) and Column (MyOutputValue) according to my needs.

When I want to test my script, even with hard coded values, I always get the same error:

`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows().`

I have no clue what's going wrong here. Any idea?

Here my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
#region Members
    String MyOutputValue;
#endregion

public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();


    MyOutputValue = "test";

    CreateNewOutputRows();

}

public override void PostExecute()
{

base.PostExecute();
}

public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    OutputRowsBuffer.AddRow();

    OutputRowsBuffer.MyOutputValue = MyOutputValue;
}
}
```

Within my SSIS Package I start debug and then I get the following screen (it is german, so I translated the error into english for this post):
[image]

Comment: Exactly where do you get the exception? Please post the stack trace.

Comment: I added the message I get when I debug the Package. This is all what I have. Would you need me to add something more in the code to give you more info about the error?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SSIS runtime doesn't initialize output buffers (such as your `OutputRowsBuffer` object) until **after** the `PreExecute` method returns.

Unfortunately, your `PreExecute` method is calling `CreateNewOutputRows` **directly**, which is causing the `NullReferenceException`. Instead, you should let the SSIS runtime call `CreateNewOutputRows` (which it will, at the appropriate point in the execution cycle):

```
public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();

    MyOutputValue = "test";

    // Do NOT call CreateNewOutputRows from PreExecute!
    // CreateNewOutputRows(); 
}

public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    OutputRowsBuffer.AddRow();
    OutputRowsBuffer.MyOutputValue = MyOutputValue;
}
```

See [Creating a Source with the Script Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136060.aspx) page on MSDN for additional sample code.